# Why random effects explain more variance than fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, crossed-random-effects

I have run a mixed-effects model that included fixed effects as well as random intercepts and random slopes. The design of the experiment is *crossed*: there are participants, each of whom evaluate a subset of words, and there are words, each of which is presented to a subset of participants.

I have calculated the *R*<sup>2</sup> for the fixed and the random effects, using [Nakagawa et al.'s (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsif.2017.0213) formula, and I have found that the random effects explain more variance than the fixed effects, which I think is the usual pattern for models containing a maximal random-effects structure. I'm trying to provide a succinct explanation for why the random effects explain more variance. I would be very grateful indeed if someone could please consider this attempt and perhaps point out any weaknesses.

> It is to be expected that random effects explain more variance, as they involve a far larger number of coefficients for each effect. For instance, the by-word random slopes for a single individual-level variable (e.g., vocabulary size) involve as many coefficients as the number of words. Similarly, the by-participant random slopes for a single word-level variable (e.g., language-based similarity) involve as many coefficients as the number of participants. In contrast, a fixed effect involves 1 coefficient only.

To be more specific, I am worried about the last sentence. Is the 1 very wrong or acceptable? Would you explain it differently?

Comment: The statement "a fixed effect involves 1 coefficient only" is not always true (but may very well be true in your model). Examples where it's not true: Predictor X is numeric and we include a polynomial or a spline of X in the model. Or predictor X is categorical with more than two categories. Perhaps instead of trying for a very general statement you can make statements that are true for your model.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was super helpful. In my model, there is indeed one estimate per predictor, as I recoded categorical predictors to numeric, and there aren't any polynomial, splines, etc. I think you solved my question, so thank you again! If you wanted to, please feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I would accept it.